# Filter results based on another filter's date range

Tags: sql, tableau-api

**Background:**

I have the following user's registration funnel, where user creates account and then goes through prompts with the goal of registering:

```
id  date        create_account_date user_creates_account registration_date  user_registers 
1   12/30/2017  12/30/2017          1                    12/30/2017         1
2   12/30/2017  12/30/2017          1                    1/2/2018           0
2   1/2/2018    12/30/2017          0                    1/2/2018           1
3   12/31/2017  12/31/2017          1                    12/31/2017         1
4   1/1/2018    1/1/2018            1                    1/3/2018           0
4   1/3/2018    1/1/2018            0                    1/3/2018           1
5   1/1/2018    1/1/2018            1                    1/1/2018           1
6   1/2/2018    1/2/2018            1                    1/3/2018           0
6   1/3/2018    1/2/2018            0                    1/3/2018           1
7   1/3/2018    1/3/2018            1                    1/3/2018           1
8   1/4/2018    1/4/2018            1                    1/4/2018           1
```

In aggregate:

```
                      12/30  12/31  1/1  1/2  1/3  1/4  Total  Total 1/2-1/4
User Creates Account  2      1      2    1    1    1    8      3
User Registers        1      1      1    1    3    1    8      5
```

**Issue:**

I am trying to add a date filter, where I can pick the date range of the data I want to see.

- I added `create_account_date` as filter, and picked Jan 2 to Jan 4. However, that will only force `min(registration date)='1/2/18'`, while `max(registration date)` can happen after Jan 4.
- I also tried forcing `create_account_date = registration_date`, but that understates those who registered on a day different from `create_account_date`, but still within the filtered date range.

**Ask:**

I would like to be able to filter the output by the date range filter/parameter. 
So `create_account_date` and `registration date` per user are >= `min(date)` and `create_account_date` and `registration date` per user are <= `max(date)`. Here `create_account_date` >= `registration date`

So with filter implementation I would have:

```
                      1/2/2018  1/3/2018    1/4/2018    Total
User Creates Account  1         1           1           3
User Registers        0         1           1           2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should be final report, can you post a sample report layout with create account date and registration date, BEcause in a single sheet you are trying to manipulate two different filters

Comment: @Siva question updated with full details

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Siva unfortunately not

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying in a wrong way don't try to manipulate create account and registration date instead add a filter only for normal date field and place the fields in sheet and see the result.

If you really want to create a filter then you can't add the condition just using normal filter instead you need to create a two parameters.

One parameter for start date

One parameter for end date

For both the parameters use date field to display the list of data

Now create two calcualted fields

```
If create account date >=[start date parameter] and create account date < [end date parameter]
then 
your field
end
```

Similarly

```
If registration date >=[start date parameter] and registration date < [end date parameter]
then 
your field
end
```

USe both the fileds in rows and place date in column of sheet

Comment: Makes so much sense! Thank you

Comment: What if I have 10+ columns, is there a way to not create a calculated field for each field?

Comment: As per your data columns are from date field and that is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on the goal, but it sounds like you want to find users where the `account_create_date` is between a start and end date AND the `registration_date` is between a start and end date. If that's so, you could filter with `WHERE (create_account_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date) AND (registration_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date)`. My syntax assumes SQL Server, but you can make it work for other DBMS too.

Comment: the reason this wouldnt work is because registration date of Jan 2-4 (between start and end) will include registration for users creating accounts before Jan 2-4. I dont want that

Comment: My mistake, change the query to use `AND` between sub clauses instead of `OR`. I'll edit the answer now to reflect this.

Comment: unfortunately this also wouldnt work because it will understate sum users creating accounts since it forces create account date to equal registration date, but there are dates where account is created but no registration occurs.

Comment: This will still work. Example: John Smith creates account on 5/2/2018 and registers on 5/3/2018. With the above query, if you pass in `@start_date = '5/1/2018'`, `@end_date = '5/4/2018'`, then you'll find John Smith even though the `create_account_date <> registration_date`.

Comment: Are you saying you want to also get Jane Smith if she creates her account on 5/2/2018 but doesn't register until 5/10/2018 if you pass in `@start_date = '5/1/2018'`, `@end_date = '5/4/2018'`? If that's the case, then the query should be `WHERE (create_account_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date) AND ((registration_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date) OR registration_date IS NULL)`.

Comment: I will try your last suggestion. Updated question with full details to clarify

Comment: This includes more users with registration date in the range, but it still decreases the number of users creating accounts due to the "and" clause

Comment: I made some assumptions about the data that are incorrect. I had thought you only had one record per user in the underlying table. It looks like you can have 2 records: one at the time of creation and one at the time of registration. Is this correct? If so, why is there only one record for IDs 1, 3, 5, 7, and 8? Is that because these users registered on the same date they created their account? If so, for IDs 2, 4, and 6 are there 2 records for each ID because the registration happened on a later date? A query can handle these conditions, I just need to understand how the table is being used.